# iptables nat redirect to port if port open?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm running a router that I need filter some http request by proxy for blocked some domain request. so how can I make sure connection always available to destination even when proxy down?

I need:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1 # if 127.0.0.1:80 open
```

but if `127.0.0.1:80` is dead, how can I implement PREROUTING rule return like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dport 80 -j RETURN # if 127.0.0.1:80 dead
```

its possible using NQA（Network Quality Analyzer）+ Track solve it？

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the port isn't open, clients will just get the same connection refused error anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton because I'm running a router that I need filter some http request by proxy for blocked some domain request. so if proxy is not available it will connect to destination directly

Comment: You can add and delete the rule when you start and stop the proxy, then.

Comment: @MichaelHampton good though, but what if proxy shutdown by unknown events?

Comment: Then presumably the users will complain and the admin will come round and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no option to let iptables determine if a port is up / working.

There are two ways to work arround that problem that come up my mind.

1. **Run a script periodically** to check the state of the port

   You could write a little bash script that checks if the port is opened and perform the required tasks. An easy way to look up if TCP ports are opend via `nc` is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15886087/8179604). This script could be run periodically via cron.
2. **Create a wrapper script** for starting and stoping the actual service

   This script would be used to start and stop the service running at port 80. if would add the first iptables rule and then call the actual script that starts the service. On the other way you would first remove the first rule, add the second rule and then call the script to stop the service.

Comment: that solution can not fix this side effect that when service shutdown need a window time to recovery service. thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: how about --state option?